# Dynamic Control Styles

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have a WPF window appliaction that I would like to build the functionality to have a dynamic style (font family, weight, size, etc) that is stored in a SQL database allowing a user to specify the type of style to use on control's such as ListView's and labels, etc.

I have started defining styles in the Application.XAML file and am not sure if this is the best approach to achieve a dynamic style.

My application will give the ability for the user to define particular styles to apply to the controls so I would need the application to be able to update the styles without having to restart the application.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yow want something like this -
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfskins.aspx